# Moq: Mock.Verify() throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have some simple interface and I'm writing a simple unit test that invokes a `Mock<>` of it.

```
public interface IMy() {
  void Method(ISomething foo, byte[] bar);
}

var mock = new Mock<IMy>;
// ...
mock.Verify(m => m.Method(It.IsAny<ISomething>(), It.IsAny<byte[]>()), Times.Exactly(10));
```

However, the `Verify` throws the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__92`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.String.Join(String separator, IEnumerable`1 values)
   at Moq.Extensions.GetValue(Object value)
   at Moq.Extensions.<>c.<Format>b__1_1(Object a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Moq.Extensions.Format(ICallContext invocation)
   at Moq.Mock.<>c.<FormatInvocations>b__63_0(ICallContext i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Moq.Mock.FormatInvocations(IEnumerable`1 invocations)
   at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Times times)
```

Debugger doesn't help much to find what exactly could be `null` here. Did anyone encounter it using `Moq` library?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet of pseudo-code? It would be easier to help you if we could reproduce the exact error.

Comment: Duplicate of "what is null"? Really... Ok I'll move the question to Moq github, maybe they'll care

Comment: If you can demonstrate that it's *not* a duplicate, the question can be reopened. The best way of doing that is to provide a [mcve] as I suggested shortly after you asked the question.

Comment: Found the issue in their github, at least I learned to look there first. If you'll un-mark it as duplicate I could post an answer for anyone encountering this in the future.

Comment: I can't do that - I don't have enough reputation. But even if I did, I probably wouldn't do it while the question is still in its current state - I'd want to see a [mcve] first. That would make the question *much* better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the problem was that Moq internally uses the mock's implementation of `IEnumerable`. In future versions of the library, the error message and precondition checks were improved.

See following discussions for reference:

First error - not the same stack trace but root cause:
https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/169

Second error - same stack trace:
https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/464

Better check in a library Github when its an open source fault.

Comment: Any workaround to solve this issue? I am still getting the same error (moq  version is 4.14.2)